# How do I make my program continue only if the user enters certain values?

Tags: java

My code is supposed to simulate something similar to a vending machine. But there is a problem when I enter a price that is not one of my options, e.g. *0.82* the program still runs. How do I get it to only accept one of my options?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VendingMachine 
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        double price;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Choose your price. Your options are: ");
        double i;
        for (i=0.25; i<=1.25; i+=0.25)
             System.out.printf("$%.2f\n", i );

        System.out.println("Enter your selection now: ");
        price=keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.printf("You chose the $%.2f option. ",price);    
        double deposit;

        if (price<=1.00) {
            System.out.println("Please insert 1 dollar. *This machine only accepts Loonies*");
            deposit=1;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please insert 2 dollars.*This machine only accepts Loonies*");
            deposit=2;
        }

        System.out.println("Please press 'Enter' to simulate inserting money. ");
        new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();

        double change;
        change = deposit-price;
        System.out.printf("Your change is $%.2f\n",change);
    }
}
```

I tried something like this but it doesn't work. What is the best way to do this.

```
if (price==i)
    System.out.println("You entered " + price);
else {
    System.out.println("Invalide choice. Please try again.")
    System.exit(0);
}
```

*[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmmpL.png) is an image if you find it easier to read.*

Comment: "this doesn't work" is not informative enough. please post the full code, the input and expected output vs. *real* output

Comment: Have you tried to run it under debugger to see values of `price` and `i` just before your `if`?

Comment: I think you should give options like *1 2 3* or *A) B) C)* rather than getting the value. Then use a *switch* statement to get the *default* if the given value isn't correct.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to point out that I am aware I can run else if statements on my 5 options quite easily. But if there were way more options than 5, how could I do it with out repeating else if a whole bunch of times? Or is that the best way?? Thanks again.

Comment: alfasin the program runs with out error but no matter what I put as input it tells me invalid selection. If you click on the image link you can see my input and output very clearly

Comment: Then you should use a `Map` ,as `key` should be the options you give to the user as I said above,you shouldn't read numeric values from the user. The reason is he can enter whatever he wants.

Comment: PM no I still need to work on using my debugger, I am terrible at it right now.

Comment: A Map? I will have to google that. Sorry again guys I am really new to this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the user to enter only your displayed prices, I suggest the following, you shall edit to your exact desires.

```
    //given you an open scanner
    boolean isCorrectPrice = false;

    System.out.println("enter price");
    price = in.nextDouble();
    while(!isCorrectPrice)
    {
       if(price%0.25==0 && price<=1.25 && price>0)
       {
          System.out.println("you entered "+price);
          IsCorrectPrice = true;
          continue;
       }
       System.out.println("incorrect price, re-enter ");
       price = in.nextDouble();
    }
   //your code after user enters correct price
```

That will do the check. If your prices change, all you have to do is change the maximum price provided its still dividable with *0.25* or the condition price check.

Comment: Hey this works great! I wish I had tried it sooner. I was just trying to go through and understand all of the other posts first. This is my favorite one. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use some sort of loop ([while](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html), [do-while](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html), [for](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)), which will continue to excecute the code until a condition is (or isn't) met.

Here is an example:

```
do {
   code line 1;
   code line 2;
   code line 3;
   ...
} while(yourCondition);
```

If `yourCondition` is satisfied (`yourCondition == true`), the code will go back to `code line 1` (will perform the code block between `do` and `while`) and it'll stop once the condition isn't satisfied(`yourCondition == false`). `yourCondition` could be any expression that returns a true/false result (`boolean`), such as `2+2==4`.

If you want to keep looping for as long as `yourCondition` isn't met, you can add a `!` before your expression, which will evaluate the opposite of your `boolean` like this `(!yourCondition)`.

Now, if you understood how that works, you can easily apply it to your code.

Comment: Wow I wasn't expecting so many answers so quickly. Thanks guys! I try this:

    do
    {
        System.out.println("Enter your selection: ");
        price=keyboard.nextDouble();
    }
    while (price != i)

But it just repeats Enter your selection now no matter what my input is.

Comment: then either `i` or `price` don't have the value you suspect. Using the debugger you can check whats wrong (or you can just print the value of `i` and `price` right before the `while`

Comment: Outside of my for statement, i is equal to 1.75... But I don't really understand why. I tried putting my do-while inside of my for statement, and I've tried putting my for statement inside of my do-while statement, but I keep getting a ton of errors. How do I make i equal all of my options?

Comment: A better way to word my question maybe, is how do I extend what is in my for loop through out my entire program?

Comment: Sorry I keep re-posting on here, but for example, if I put:

    for (i=0.25; i<=2; i+=0.25)
        System.out.printf("$%.2f\n", i );
    System.out.println(i);

The 'i' outside of my for will equal 2.25. (It always equals .25 more than the max value in my for statement) Why?

Comment: in your `for` you are increasing the value of `i` every time you loop by `.25` (when you say `i+=0.25`, which is equivalent to `i = i + 0.25`). I don't think you understand how for-loops work, read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Comment: Ya I know I have a lot of work to do before I get any good at this. Thanks for the help

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :) Try to do some more research next time tho, moderators are really strict, you are lucky you didn't get your question closed. Also don't forget to mark an accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Use BigDecimal (instead of double) to work with money.  Its exact -- double isn't.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

I would write a function to get the user input.  It would not return until the
user had entered an allowed value.

Answer (score 0):

Although my real answer is the one on the comments, you can use something like this. To check recursively if the correct value was given.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VendingMachine {

    static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Choose your price. Your options are: ");
        for (double i = 0.25; i <= 1.25; i += 0.25) {
            System.out.printf("$%.2f\n", i);
        }

        double price = checkMultipleValues(0.25,1.25, 0.25);

        System.out.printf("You chose the $%.2f option. ", price);

        double deposit;
        if (price <= 1.00) {
            System.out.println("Please insert 1 dollar. *This machine only accepts Loonies*");
            deposit = 1;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please insert 2 dollars.*This machine only accepts Loonies*");
            deposit = 2;
        }

        System.out.println("Please press 'Enter' to simulate inserting money. ");
        new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();

        double change;
        change = deposit - price;
        System.out.printf("Your change is $%.2f\n", change);
    }

    private static double checkMultipleValues(double initial,double last,double step) {

        System.out.println("Enter your selection now: ");
        double price = keyboard.nextDouble();

        for (double i = initial; i <= last; i += step) {
            if (price == i) {
                return price;
            }
        }

        return checkMultipleValues( initial, last, step);
    }
}
```

***ADDENDUM***

---

Since you like @Sello answer why don't you combine it with @MrD and have something like

```
do {
    System.out.println("enter price");
    price = in.nextDouble();
//    System.out.println("you entered " + price);
} while (!(price % 0.25 == 0 && price <= 1.25 && price > 0));
```

Comment: Hi yannis. I hope you don't think I've been ignoring you. I've just been trying to juggle all these new concepts and understand what everyone is trying to tell me. I am going to try the program again afterwards, if I can get this one to work, and I'll try using the switch statement. I have read about it in my book but haven't tried it yet. Thanks for all the great advice!

Comment: Hey it took me a while but I finally got around to going over this code. It works perfectly. I didn't do it right away because I didn't recognize some things and to be honest it looked kind of overwhelming. I am going to do some reading tonight and try and master what you put down here. Thanks again for the help

Comment: I've been trying to upvote everyone that helped but my rep is too low. I just started this account. Sorry.